# How do I change the bytes of a 32-bit integer?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm trying to add two binary numbers together using only logical statements and binary arithmetic operators. But I'm confused on how to actually change the bits. It is mostly the out variable that I am trying to change, but it keeps getting zeroed every time I print it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void execute_add(int a, int b){

int i = 0;
int bit;
int bit2;
int carryOut = 0;
int out = 10;
int overflow = 0;

for(i = 0; i <32 ; i++){

  bit = (a >> i) & 1;
  bit2 = (b >> i) & 1;

  if(bit==1 && bit2==1 && carryOut == 0){
        carryOut = 1;
        out = 0 | (0x1 >> i);

  }else if(bit==1 && bit2==1 && carryOut == 1){
        carryOut = 1;
        out = 1 | (0x1 >> i);

  }else if(bit==0 && bit2==0 && carryOut == 0){
        carryOut = 0;
        out= 0 | (0x1 >> i);

  }else if(bit==0 && bit2==0 && carryOut == 1){
        carryOut = 0;
        out = 1 | (0x1 >> i);

  }else if(bit==1 && bit2==0 && carryOut == 0){
        carryOut = 0;
        out = 1 | (0x1 >> i);

  }else if(bit==1 && bit2==0 && carryOut == 1){
        carryOut = 1;
        out = 0 | (0x1 >> i);

  }else if(bit==0 && bit2==1 && carryOut == 0){
        carryOut = 0;
        out = 1 | (0x1 >> i);

  }else if(bit==0 && bit2==1 && carryOut == 1){
        carryOut = 1;
        out = 0  | (0x1 >> i);

  }else{

  }//if else

 }//for loop

   printf("\n");

   bit = (a >> 31) & 1;
   bit2 = (a >> 31)& 1;
   int bit3 = (out >> 31) & 1;

   if( bit == 1 && bit2== 1 && bit3 == 0){
     overflow = 1;

   }else if (bit == 0 && bit2 == 0 && bit3 == 1){
   overflow = 1;

   }else{

   }//overflow check

    int j;
    int g = 0;

    for(j = 31; j>=0; j--){

            if(g%4==0 && g!=0){
             printf(" ");
            }

        bit2 = (out >> j) & 1;

        printf("%d", bit2);
        g++;
    }

            printf("\n");
}

int main (){

  int a = 34;
  int b = 17;

  execute_add(a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to step thru your code line by line. `bit2 = (out >> i) & 1;` e.g. Use a debugger to answer: What value is `i` at that point? Did you mean to use `j` instead of `i`?

Comment: good catch!  But there is still a problem with the out variable being 0.

Comment: `(0x1 >> i)` is 0 for `i > 0`;

Comment: With all that shifting I propose you change the data type to `unsigned`. If you are trying to mimic the processor operation, well it has no concept of signed. It only sets appropriate flags.

Comment: That's just one example. There are too many errors in your code. Use a debugger to step thru it line by line to check that the values are what you expect them to be. As soon as you find one error correct that, rinse and repeat. If you find an error that you can't understand then come ask about that specific error. The point is to learn to debug effectively for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

With each of these statements in your for loop:

```
out = 0 | x;
```

You're resetting `out`, and clearing away all the work you've already done. You probably mean to do:

```
out = out | x
```

Or, equivalently,

```
out |= x
```

You also are right-shifting `1` all over the place, which is not what you're looking for; for any shift greater than zero, that's going to give you zero. I think you're often looking for a left-shift where you use a right shift.

I would second kaylum's comment about using a debugger; even if you flip the appropriate shifts and `|` with `out` properly, you're still going to have logic errors that will be easily fixed with a debugger.